# Is there an alternative way to filter xml elements without the E4X syntax?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, e4x

I am trying to compile some old actionscript code (part of flash app) to JS using [Jangaroo](https://github.com/CoreMedia/jangaroo-tools). Jangaroo does not support the E4X syntax and it fails at things like the double-dot operator `..` or the brackets filters `a.(CONDITION)`. So I need to rewrite those portions of code using plain ActionScript.

For the double-dot operator, I used the instead the method `descendants()` but I could not find alternative way to write the brackets filter.

Here is the original code I had:

```
B = xml..destination.(@id == someId)
```

I wrote it now:

```
B = xml.descendants("destination").(@id == someId)
```

But I still want to remove `.(@id == someId)`.

I am thinking of something like:

```
if (xml.descendants("destination").attribute("id") == someId)
{
B = xml.descendants("destination")
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

So here is how I proceeded. I have not tested its functionality, but the compiler passed it.

```
var destinations:XMLList = null;
for each (var elm in xml.descendants("destination") )
{
 if ( elm.attribute("id") == someId )
 {
    destinations += elm;
 }
}
```

Comment: Did this work? I think rather than `null`, you should be initializing `destinations` to `new XMLList()`